# Weird output on converting code from C to Python

Tags: python

I could successfully rum a simple program to check whether the number is prime or not in C. The code looks like this

```
void isPrime(int n)
{
    int a=0,i;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
    if(n%i==0)
    a++;
    }
    if(a==2)
    {
        printf("\n%d is prime",n);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n%d is not prime",n);
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{


 for(int i=2;i<=20;i++)
 {
     isPrime(i);
 }

    return 0;
}
```

The above code runs perfectly when I compile. I am a beginner in python and I have converted the same code into python, which looks like this.

```
def isPrime(n):
    a=0
    for x in range(1,n):
        if n%x==0:
            a=a+1   
    if a==2:
        print("{} is prime".format(n))
    else:
        print("{} is not prime".format(n))

for n in range(2,20):
    isPrime(n)
```

But I get a wrong output in python. The output is somewhat weird which says

```
2 is not prime
3 is not prime
4 is prime
5 is not prime
6 is not prime
7 is not prime
8 is not prime
9 is prime
10 is not prime
11 is not prime
12 is not prime
13 is not prime
14 is not prime
15 is not prime
16 is not prime
17 is not prime
18 is not prime
19 is not prime
```

I have found out that the count of 'a' is 1 less than the actual count required. For example, in case of n=8, a should be 4. But its getting counted as 3.
What could be the reason?

Comment: I think it should be `for x in range(1, n+1)`. `range` is not inclusive for the upper bound.

Comment: `range()` is half-open. Meaning `range(1,4)` will produce `[1,2,3]` not `[1,2,3,4]` so the range never includes itself.

Comment: You're probably aware of this, but it is a very inefficient way of finding whether a number is prime.  The issue is completely tangential to the translation problems, but don't use this code anywhere near a production system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you add some `print` statements so you can see where the code fails? Adding some prints should be your first reflex when debugging.

```
def isPrime(n):
    a=0
    for x in range(1,n):
        print('x,a', x,a)
        if n%x==0:
            print('incrementing a...')
            a=a+1
    print('a after loop:', a)
    if a==2:
        print("{} is prime".format(n))
    else:
        print("{} is not prime".format(n))
```

Output for `isPrime(2)`:

```
x,a 1 0
incrementing a...
a after loop: 1
2 is not prime
```

Output for `isPrime(7)`:

```
x,a 1 0
incrementing a...
x,a 2 1
x,a 3 1
x,a 4 1
x,a 5 1
x,a 6 1
a after loop: 1
7 is not prime
```

As you can see, `a` is never 2 because the `n%n` test is never executed, because with `x in range(1,n)`, the last value for `x` is `n-1`. However, if you change your `range` to `range(1,n+1)`, the test will be made:

```
x,a 1 0
incrementing a...
x,a 2 1
x,a 3 1
x,a 4 1
x,a 5 1
x,a 6 1
x,a 7 1
incrementing a...
a after loop: 2
7 is prime
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have is that the last value produced `range(start, stop)` is `stop-1`; see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range). Thus, `isPrime` should have the following `for` loop:

```
for x in range(1, n+1):
```

This will faithfully replicate the C code, and produce the correct output. (Note that this is also why you are only checking the numbers [2, 19] for whether they're prime, as opposed to [2, 20].)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem was with your range as mentioned above. Can I give you some short tips to make your code more "Pythonic"? :)

Instead of
`if n%x==0`
you would simply write
`if not n%x`

and instead of 
`a=a+1`
you could use the in-place operator, e.g.,
`a += 1`
Here, it wouldn't make much of a difference, but if you are working with mutable objects (due to the `__iadd__` method, I have more details [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/One-Python-benchmark-per-day/blob/master/ipython_nbs/day14_inplace_operators.ipynb?create=1)) you would gain a significant performance increase, e.g.,

```
def slow(a):
    for i in range(1000):
        a = a + [1,2]

def fast(a):
    for i in range(1000):
        a += [1,2]

a = []
b = []
%timeit -r 3 -n 1000 slow(a)
%timeit -r 3 -n 1000 fast(b)
```

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 2.94 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 181 µs per loop
```

Same for the binary operator instead of the `format()` method, however, I like the latter one better (due to its more powerful minilanguange and I would recommend it if you don't care about speed in certain computations)

```
%timeit -r 3 -n 1000 '{} World'.format('Hello')
%timeit -r 3 -n 1000 '%s World' %('Hello')

1000 loops, best of 3: 472 ns per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 27.3 ns per loop
```

```
def isPrime(n):
    a = 0
    for x in range(1, n+1):
        if not n%x:
            a += 1   
    if a==2:
        print("{} is prime".format(n))
    else:
        print("{} is not prime".format(n))

for n in range(2, 20):
    isPrime(n)
```

Comment: or just `print(n != 1 and not any(not n%x for x in range(2,n)))`